# Challenge bacteria simulation geometry node

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I am trying to develop a bacteria generator from the geometry node.

My example in reference is this :

> https://youtu.be/p5517XmtV8k?t=66

I think this is hard challenge for blender, this reference was probably made on Houdini.

---

My progression has brought me to this level (*download .blend end description, I use blender 3.1.0*)

[image]

- From there, the first challenge is that a bacteria must be born from another bacteria.

But I can't find a method to distribute point on point. I distribute first points on faces, but i need distribute again points but by last points this time.
[image]
My method distribute points on face and i must have a face for distribute another, but it's not at the same location.

- The second challenge is to simulate some collision, like a a rigid body content.

By chance, the bacteria have a simple form. We can imagine a bounding box and repulse another when they come to penetrate each other.

I have make a some starting but the math zone for move by each instance by others is quite obscure to me.
[image]

- The third challenge is to connect mesh bacteria like metaball just during the separation.

I think use the technique transfert bacteria to volume, and volume to mesh, or add a remesh modifier in end position, but when 2 bacteria is separated but near, i don't want they fusion again.

Any advice on whether Blender can do it ? thx all

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your 2nd challenge. Do you think of something like bacteria billard - one bacteria pushing others and loosing speed itself?

Comment: Are you bound to geometry nodes? Is scripting allowed? Could perhaps even using Boids be a solution?

Comment: Yes bacteria pushing others like bacteria billard, I have not tried with boids, I thought geometry node would be the best tool, apart from scripting. Thx for your answer.

Comment: There is no way, to transfer state from one frame to the other in geometry nodes (GN). Thus you would have to precalculate the whole simulation. And if you do this, it would be recalculated every frame. - Alternatively you could bridge every two frames with a script, so that you transfer the output of the GN of the one frame to the input of the next. This way you could possibly create something like a GN boid implementation. Then you still had to implement the whole "billard"-physics. - Long story short: It will probably be possible with GN, but pure GN is not the best tool for it.

Answer (score 0):

## Challenge 1 – bacteria born by bacteria

[image: result]

[image: node setup]

[image]

Create a *Meshline* and transfer the position of the original points to the points of the *Meshline*. Then add an offset as it suits you. I just chose a static value, but you may choose a random instead. Additionally, I added a *Birth Rate*, so that only some of the bacteria get a child.